# Adding all the quotients in the loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add to total of all the quotients for a part of my program. The part below is supposed to print out if a number is divisible through a certain range and add the sum of the quotients. I created a variable to store the totals but when it prints out it only prints out the each individual quotients and not the sums. I think the problem is where I'm implementing totaling the sum but I'm not sure.

```
            //loop through number 1-25 and find which numbers are divisable
            for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= 25; ++divisor)
            {
                int quotient = dividend / divisor;

                if (dividend % divisor == 0)
                {
                    int sumOfQuotients = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine($"{dividend} is divisible by {divisor} ({quotient})");
                    sumOfQuotients += quotient;
                    Console.WriteLine($"The sum of the quotients is {sumOfQuotients}");
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the initialization of `sumOfQuotients` before the loop, and the writing of the result until after:

```
var dividend = 10;
int sumOfQuotients = 0;
//loop through number 1-25 and find which numbers are divisable
for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= 25; ++divisor)
{
    int quotient = dividend / divisor;
    if (dividend % divisor == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{dividend} is divisible by {divisor} ({quotient})");
        sumOfQuotients += quotient;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"The sum of the quotients is {sumOfQuotients}");
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rsfu7r